# Format tooltip numbers in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use `tooltip.pointFormat` to render additional data in the tooltip. Unfortunately only `point.x` is formatted correctly with a thousand separator.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rx1ehjk/)

```
$(function () {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: false,
    },
    lang: {
      decimalPoint: ',',
      thousandsSep: '.'
    }
  });
  $('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>' + 'Count: <b>{point.count}</b><br/>',
      shared: true
    },
    series: [{
      data: [{
        y: 20009.9,
        count: 20009.9
      }, {
        y: 10009.9,
        count: 20009.9
      }, {
        y: 40009.9,
        count: 20009.9
      }],
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
      pointInterval: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you use _dot_ as `thousandsSep` on purpose?

Comment: Yes, cause I'm in Germany.

Comment: is there any way to show thousand format as (,) and two point decimal both in single value.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting).

> Numbers are formatted with a subset of float formatting conventions
>   from the C library funciton sprintf. The formatting is appended inside
>   the variable brackets, separated by a colon. For example:
>
> - Two decimal places: "`{point.y:.2f}`"
> - Thousands separator, no decimal places: `{point.y:,.0f}`
> - Thousands separator, one decimal place: `{point.y:,.1f}`

So using `:,.1f` inside the brackets will format the number correctly.

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>' + 'Count: <b>{point.count:,.1f}</b><br/>',
  shared: true
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rx1ehjk/8/)

Comment: Note, this only worked for me if I specified the Highcharts lang decimalPoint and thousandsSep values as you did in your jsFiddle.

Answer (score 18):

Instaed of pointFormat, use the [tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and then [Highcharts.numberFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat)

```
tooltip: {
            formatter:function(){

                return this.point.series.name + ': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.options.count,1,',','.') + '</b><br/>' + 'Count: <b>'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y,1,',','.')+'</b><br/>';
            }
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8rx1ehjk/4/

Comment: I know this before and try to avoid this, cause I have to support german and english format for an whole bunch of charts. So setting the format once for all charts is much more convenient then setting it for every single chart.  Also the formatted date in the header is missing now.

Answer (score 3):

In our case [`tooltipFormatter`](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/highcharts.src.js#L12431) applies format only for `y` property, I found couple ways how to add format not only for `y`,

1. add format for each tooltip and for each property like this `point.count:,.f`

   ```
   pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.count:,.f}</b><br/>' + 'Count: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
   ```
2. create small extension like this

   ```
   (function (Highcharts) {
     var tooltipFormatter = Highcharts.Point.prototype.tooltipFormatter;

     Highcharts.Point.prototype.tooltipFormatter = function (pointFormat) {
       var keys = this.options && Object.keys(this.options),
           pointArrayMap = this.series.pointArrayMap,
           tooltip;

       if (keys.length) {
         this.series.pointArrayMap = keys;
       }     

       tooltip = tooltipFormatter.call(this, pointFormat);        
       this.series.pointArrayMap = pointArrayMap || ['y'];

       return tooltip;
     }
   }(Highcharts));
   ```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/8rx1ehjk/10/)